# In \bibliographystyle{alpha}, can I sort references by the first author's last name instead of by the marker?

Tags: bibtex, natbib, sorting

I'm creating a bibliography using `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`. Consider the following three references.

> [Gab72] Peter Gabriel...
>
> [GJ09] Paul G. Goerss and John F. Jardine...
>
> [GR92] Peter Gabriel and Andrei V. Roiter...

They are automatically being displayed in my LaTeX file in the ordering above. This is alphabetical order by the marker: [Gab72] < [GJ09] < [GR92]. Is it possible to instead have the ordering based on alphabetical ordering of the first author's last name? This would instead give the following ordering:

> [Gab72] Peter Gabriel...
>
> [GR92] Peter Gabriel and Andrei V. Roiter...
>
> [GJ09] Paul G. Goerss and John F. Jardine...

I would prefer this latter ordering because then Peter Gabriel's references are adjacent.

Comment: If you're willing to use `biblatex`, `\usepackage[sorting=nty,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}` should do the trick...

Comment: @Jonathan: I've tried using biblatex, but now whenever an entry has four or more authors, it suppresses all initials; e.g., I'd like to see [DEFG88] instead of [Dir+88] for a paper written by Dirac, Einstein, Fermat, and Galois; also, it doesn't work with {\relax } to treat multiple letters as one (e.g. for Hungarian authors). Can the problem above be solved within bibtex?

Comment: @MarcoGolla Check out the `maxnames` option of `biblatex`. Also, there is the option to use unicode and even giving each entry a field to be used for sorting only. Unfortunately the `biblatex` documentation can be quite overwhelming, but searching for `maxnames` and sorting might help.

Comment: The answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472951/35864 discusses sorting alphabetic styles and has a solution for a `babalpha`-based style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have only the problem with this one. The simple solution is

```
@Misc{GR92, 
title = {Title Text}, 
author= {Peter Gabriel and Andrei V. Roiter...}, 
year= {2019}, 
sortkey = {Gac}, 
}
```

I'm not sure what you use so try `sort`, `sortkey`, or `presort`.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like a more systematic solution, rather than an ad hoc one.

Comment: can you post more code? Are  you using natbib biber or biblatex. A functional minimal example of code would be nice