# Why does babalpha remove dashes?

Tags: bibtex, babel

Continuing https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472956/165772 and https://gist.github.com/moewew/6a59fc23db6d2ab219b6f189a3645a06 , I noticed that the dash in name of an author may get replaced by a space. Namely, running the standard pdflatex-bibtex loop on

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british,finnish,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @PHDTHESIS{Back-OnTheCorrectnessOfRefinementStepsInProgramDevelopment,
  author = {Ralph-Johan Back},
  title = {On the correctness of refinement steps in program development},
  school = {\foreignlanguage{finnish}{Åbo Akademi}, Department of Computer Science},
  year = 1978,
  address = {Helsinki, Finland},
  note = {Report A--1978--4},
  OPTpdf = {http://www.it.abo.fi/crest/publications/public/1978/OnTheCorrectnessOfRefinementStepsInProgramDevelpmentTR.pdf},
  language={british}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{babelbib} % Multilingual bibliographies
\begin{document}
\cite{Back-OnTheCorrectnessOfRefinementStepsInProgramDevelopment}
\bibliographystyle{babalpha-fl-gs-sort}%%% Same with \bibliographystyle{babalpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

produces

> ...
>
> [Bac78] Ralph Johan Back: *On the correctness of refinement steps in program*
>
> ...

In particular, there is no hyphen between Ralph and Johan, whereas there should be one. While it is certainly easy to work around this issue on a case-by-case bases by means of replacing `-` with `{-}`, I'm wondering whether there might be a more permanent bugfix. In this sense, I'd appreciate it if your answer would involve improving @moewe's `babalpha-fl-gs-sort` rather than the original `babalpha-fl`.

(P.S. If anyhow possible, I don't really want to change from babalpha-fl-gs-sort to some other style or from bibtex to biber, since it would incur a range of other compatibility problems in a non-minimal example with tons of other packages and, most likely, extra changes in formatting that a publisher would have to agree to.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a quirk of BibTeX's name formatting routine. Q35 in [`btxFAQ`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/btxFAQ.pdf) seems to be extremely related.

When `babalpha` formats names it inserts the customisable macro `\btxfnamespacelong` between first name elements. This happens with the following invocation

```
s nameptr "{ff{\btxfnamespacelong } }{vv~}" format.name$
```

Apparently, BibTeX not only splits names separated with a space such as `Rolph Johan`, but also names connected with a hyphen such as `Ralph-Johan` for the purposes of inserting content between first name elements and even discards the hyphen, so you end up with `Ralph\btxfnamespacelong Johan`.

---

A cheap workaround would be something like

```
\newcommand*{\myhyphen}{-}
```

and then

```
author = {Ralph\myhyphen{}Johan Back},
```

For BibTeX `Ralph\myhyphen{}Johan` is a unit that won't be split into two first names `Ralph` and `Johan`,  so you end up with the expected output.

---

Another work-around that keeps the `.bib` content sane would be to simply tell the `.bst` style not to bother with `\btxfnamespacelong`. Since `\btxfnamespacelong` is a normal space in all default settings of `babelbib` anyway you don't stand to lose a lot from removing this bit of the definition.

Search for `{ff{\btxfnamespacelong } }` in the `.bst` and replace it with `{ff }` (there should be two hits).

---

If you want to keep `\btxfnamespacelong`, extra work is needed. Essentially we need to manually do for `{ff }` what `{ff{\btxfnamespacelong } }` does automatically.

The code to do that is stolen from `biblatex.bst`. We format with `{ff}` and later manually replace  and `~` with `\btxfnamespacelong`. In theory that could cause issues with spaces that are not a brace level `0`, but I guess one can live with that.

The diff to `babalpha-fl-gs-sort.bst` is

```
--- babalpha-fl-gs-sort.bst 2019-03-28 09:19:33.293644400 +0100
+++ babalpha-fl-gs-sort-dash.bst    2019-03-28 09:25:55.925628100 +0100
@@ -1,3 +1,12 @@
+%%%%%%%% `babalpha-fl-gs-sort-dash.bst'
+%%%%%%%% even more tweaks for `babalpha-fl-gs-sort.bst'
+%%%%%%%% for https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/481557/35864
+%%%%%%%% this time we need to emulate {ff{\btxfnamespacelong } }
+%%%%%%%% most code stolen from biblatex.bst
+%%%%%%%% 2019-03-28 MW
+%%%%%%%%
+%%%%%%%% header of older versions follow
+%%%%%%%%
 %%%%%% `babalpha-fl-gs-sort.bst'
 %%%%%% babalpha-fl-gs with tweaked sorting
 %%%%%% for https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472951/35864
@@ -76,6 +85,7 @@
     after.sentence
     after.block
     before.title
+    resvctra
   }

 STRINGS
@@ -84,6 +94,7 @@
     language.state
     change.temp
     isbn.command
+    resvstrga resvstrgb resvstrgc
   }

 FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
@@ -382,6 +393,35 @@

 INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

+% from biblatex.bst
+FUNCTION {str:length} {
+  #1 'resvctra :=
+  { duplicate$ duplicate$ #1 resvctra substring$ = not }
+    { resvctra #1 + 'resvctra := }
+  while$
+  pop$
+  resvctra
+}
+
+FUNCTION {str:replace} {
+  'resvstrga :=
+  'resvstrgb :=
+  'resvstrgc :=
+  resvstrgb str:length 'resvctra :=
+  ""
+  { resvstrgc empty$ not }
+    { resvstrgc #1 resvctra substring$ resvstrgb =
+        { resvstrga *
+          resvstrgc #1 resvctra + global.max$ substring$ 'resvstrgc :=
+        }
+        { resvstrgc #1 #1 substring$ *
+          resvstrgc #2 global.max$ substring$ 'resvstrgc :=
+        }
+      if$
+    }
+  while$
+}
+
 FUNCTION {format.names}
 { 's :=
   #1 'nameptr :=
@@ -390,7 +430,11 @@
     { namesleft #0 > }
     { nameptr #1 >
       {
-        s nameptr "{ff{\btxfnamespacelong } }{vv~}" format.name$
+        s nameptr "{ff}" format.name$
+          " " "\btxfnamespacelong " str:replace
+          "~" "\btxfnamespacelong " str:replace
+        duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ { " " * } if$
+        s nameptr "{vv~}" format.name$ *
         s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ lastnamefont *
         s nameptr "{, jj}" format.name$ *
         't :=
@@ -408,7 +452,11 @@
           if$
         }
         {
-          s nameptr "{ff{\btxfnamespacelong } }{vv~}" format.name$
+          s nameptr "{ff}" format.name$
+            " " "\btxfnamespacelong " str:replace
+            "~" "\btxfnamespacelong " str:replace
+          duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ { " " * } if$
+          s nameptr "{vv~}" format.name$ *
           s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ lastnamefont *
           s nameptr "{,~jj}" format.name$ * namefont
         }
```

The changed file `babalpha-fl-gs-sort-dash.bst` can be downloaded at https://gist.github.com/moewew/db4ea9fd7a76b74ed3a12ec0802c49c0

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british,swedish,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@phdthesis{Back-OnTheCorrectnessOfRefinementStepsInProgramDevelopment,
  author   = {Ralph-Johan Back and Ralph Johan Bock},
  title    = {On the correctness of refinement steps in program development},
  school   = {\foreignlanguage{swedish}{Åbo Akademi}, Department of Computer Science},
  year     = 1978,
  address  = {Helsinki, Finland},
  note     = {Report A--1978--4},
  language = {british},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{babelbib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Back-OnTheCorrectnessOfRefinementStepsInProgramDevelopment}
\bibliographystyle{babalpha-fl-gs-sort-dash}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Ralph-Johan Back and Ralph Johan Bock: On the correctness of refinement steps in program development. PhD thesis, Åbo Akademi, Department of Computer Science, Helsinki, Finland, 1978. Report A–1978–4.]